# Elegant way for DAO testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, dao

I want to improve my DB access code tests.

I am using GAE datastore. To test the Db classes, I used a Backdoor Servlet. Just wondering, is there more efficient and elegant way to do DAO testing?
Your views on Unit vs Integration tests for DAO?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how your database is set up. Here are a couple of other options apart from what you already have:

- you can write unit tests directly against your DAOs. You can mock the database calls away with mockito.
- you can write unit tests that records the integration with the database and then replays it when you run the tests a second time. See the betamax library fot this.
- you can run unit tests against the actual database. Now it is not unit tests anymore but a kind of integration test. In this case you will need to think about how to get a clean state in the database to start from.
- you can run integration tests against the entire system and make sure that most of your database code is touched by using a code coverage tool.

I prefer to have full blown integrations tests on the whole thing including the database and any other third party integrations. And unit tests on the particulars but not necessarily involving the actual database calls. But - as always - your setup may lead you in other directions.